# Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32 while multiplying the specific value from database to textbox value

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

Below this code I encountered that error. In my database employee_product, I have a column name "Unitcost" and "Quantity" both int dbdatatype. I don't know if its right to convert it to int because it is already int type in my database. product_result which my another database, I want to multiply the value of my cost in my emplyoee_product db to my quantity textbox and pass the result to Total and display the result in my product_result in the column of "Total". Please help me to construct the right way in my code.

```
int Total;
int Cost;
int Quantity;
byte[] data;


// This is the code where i get my quantity on my quantity textbox
public void DisplayQuantity()
    {
        using (var con = SQLConnection.GetConnection())
        {
            using (var select = new SqlCommand("Select * from employee_product where Codeitem = @Codeitem ", con))
            {
                select.Parameters.Add("@Codeitem", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _view.txt_code.Text;
                using (var reader = select.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        txt_quantity.Text = reader["Quantity"].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

private void btn_ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var con = SQLConnection.GetConnection())
        {
            using (var selects = new SqlCommand("Select * from employee_product where Codeitem =@Codeitem ", con))
            {
                selects.Parameters.Add("@Codeitem", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _view.txt_code.Text;
                using (var reader = selects.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        data = (byte[])reader["Image"];
                        Cost = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Unitcost"]);
                        Convert.ToInt32(Total);
                        Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(txt_quantity.Text);
                        Total = Quantity * Cost;
                    }
                }                    
            }
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("Insert into product_result (Date, Image, Code, Name, Price, Discount, Quantity, Total) Values (@Date, @Image, @Code, @Name, @Price, @Discount, @Quantity, @Total)", con))
            {

                command.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = date;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = data;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Code", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _view.txt_code.Text.Trim();
                command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _view.txt_name.Text.Trim();
                command.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _view.txt_price.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Discount", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txt_discount.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txt_quantity.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Total", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Total;

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

*Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32* indicates that you're passing `string` value to `SqlParameter` parameter which set as `SqlDbType.Int`. If the values come from textbox's `Text` property (which is a `string` property), make sure you're convert them first using either `Convert.ToInt32`, `int.Parse` or `int.TryParse` before assignment:

```
 command.Parameters.Add("@Discount", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txt_discount.Text);
 command.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txt_quantity.Text);
```

Comment: Solved ! Thank you :)